# Bootstrap multiselect get selected value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

Using Bootstrap Multi-select I want to select all the values which was already been selected before.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" required="" name="somename" multiple>
<option checked="checked" value="1">something</option>
<option checked="checked" value="2">something</option>
<option checked="checked" value="3">something</option>
</select>
```

Here checked="checked" has been populated dynamically. Though "checked="checked"" is already there but multiselect doesn't select them instead selects only the first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all put multiple attribute in select element like below:

```html
<select multiple class="form-control" required="" name="somename">
     <option checked="checked" value="1">something</option>
     <option checked="checked" value="2">something</option>
     <option checked="checked" value="3">something</option>
    </select>
```

You Had forget to add multiple attribute in your select element.
Did you see the difference between yours and my code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my code 'multiple' is already there but forgot to mention.

Comment: So how are you retrieving your selected values ? are you using javascript, jquery or php ?

Comment: <select th:name="role" class="form-control" required='' multiple="multiple" id="multiSelect">
                                    <option th:each="role : ${allRole}" th:value="${role.roleId}"
                                            th:text="${role.roleName}"
                                            th:checked="${role.status} == 1"
                                            th:field="*{roles}"></option>
                                </select>

Comment: I am totally shocked by seeing your code, you are trying to retrieve values inside an html tag, And I don't think an html tag looks like that, Or    I might be wrong.

Comment: This code: 
<select th:name="role" class="form-control" required='' multiple="multiple" id="multiSelect"> <option th:each="role : ${allRole}" th:value="${role.roleId}" th:text="${role.roleName}" th:checked="${role.status} == 1" th:field="*{roles}"></option> </select>
Produces:
<select multiple class="form-control" required="" name="somename">
     <option checked="checked" value="1">something</option>
     <option checked="checked" value="2">something</option>
     <option checked="checked" value="3">something</option>
    </select>

Comment: So how are getting the selected values then

Comment: th:checked="${role.status} == 1"

Comment: Except HTML And Css, Which language are you using ? Because I don't understand what you have written above.

Comment: I'm getting the value using Spring Boot and using Thymeleaf template engine to showcase Spring Data.

Comment: Good for you. :-)